# How can I differentiate a manual scroll (via mousewheel/scrollbar) from a Javascript/jQuery scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, scrollbar, mousewheel

### UPDATE:

Here is a [jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/eqafi/3) demonstrating the problem.

**UPDATE 2:**
And here is [the fixed version](http://jsbin.com/eqafi/4) thanks to [fudgey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/145346/fudgey).

---

Basically, I have the following javascript which scrolls the window to an anchor on the page:

```
 // get anchors with href's that start with "#"
 $("a[href^=#]").live("click", function(){
     var target = $($(this).attr("href"));
     // if the target exists: scroll to it...
     if(target[0]){
         // If the page isn't long enough to scroll to the target's position
         // we want to scroll as much as we can. This part prevents a sudden 
         // stop when window.scrollTop reaches its maximum.
         var y = Math.min(target.offset().top, $(document).height() - $(window).height());
         // also, don't try to scroll to a negative value...
         y=Math.max(y,0);
         // OK, you can scroll now...
         $("html,body").stop().animate({ "scrollTop": y }, 1000);
     }
     return false;
 });
```

It works perfectly......until I manually try to scroll the window. When the scrollbar or mousewheel is scrolled I need to stop the current scroll animation...but I'm not sure how to do this.

This is probably my starting point...

```
$(window).scroll(e){
    if(IsManuallyScrolled(e)){
        $("html,body").stop();
    }
}
```

...but I'm not sure how to code the `IsManuallyScrolled` function. I've checked out `e` (the `event` object) in Google Chrome's console and AFAIK there is not way to  differentiate between a manual scroll and jQuery's `animate()` scroll.

**How can I differentiate between a *manual* scroll and one called via jQuery's `$.fn.animate` function?**

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try this function:

```
$('body,html').bind('scroll mousedown wheel DOMMouseScroll mousewheel keyup', function(e){
 if ( e.which > 0 || e.type == "mousedown" || e.type == "mousewheel"){
  $("html,body").stop();
 }
})
```

Also, did you see [this tutorial](http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/09/animated-scrolling-with-jquery-12)?

Update: Modern browsers now use ["wheel"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_event_reference/wheel) as the event, so I've included it in the code above.

Comment: THANK YOU! No, I didn't see the tutorial, thanks for that too. Here is an updated [JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/eqafi/4) with your fix

Comment: Oh, and why use DOMMouseScroll? Does "scroll" !== "DomMouseScroll"?

Comment: `DOMMouseScroll` is for Firefox only (ref: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/scroll.html)

Comment: So jQuery doesn't map DOMMouseScroll to scroll for us?

Comment: Oddly enough, no, so to support it you'll need to use the plugin (http://plugins.jquery.com/project/mousewheel)

Comment: Just in case you are interested, I used some of your code to help someone with this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896869/jquery-changing-css-on-navigation-when-div-scrolls-into-view/2898109#2898109)... here is that demo (http://jsfiddle.net/m2zQE/) :) Cheers!

Comment: Update: added "wheel" event to the binding.

Comment: For touch screen devices you will need to add `touchstart` to your list of events, and check for it in the event itself `... || e.type == 'touchstart'`

Comment: Ironically, modern computers now rarely use wheels :)

Comment: @1GR3 Then, I'd call that a tablet; not a computer ;)

Comment: I'd say that 27" is too big for a tablet ;)

Comment: I'd say using a 27" touch screen is crazy ;)

Answer (score 2):

I had your same issue some a few days ago.You shouldn't be using jquery's animate function if you want to obtain that result, you have to simulate the animation using a polling function.

I made this class which is supposed to provide a smooth scrolldown when **ScrollDown.slow()** is called.

```
ScrollDown.current=$(window).scrollTop();
ScrollDown.lastValue;
ScrollDown.lastType;
ScrollDown.enabled=true;
ScrollDown.custom=function(value,rate){  //let's say value==='bottom' and rate=10
    if(value==='bottom'){
        value=$(document).height()-$(window).height();
    }
    ScrollDown.current=$(window).scrollTop();
    ScrollDown.lastValue=value;
    (function poll(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            var prev=$(window).scrollTop();  //This is the critical part
            /*I'm saving again the scroll position of the window, remember
            10 ms have passed since the polling has started
            At this rate, if the user will scroll up for down pre!==ScrollDown.current
            And that means I have to stop scrolling.*/
            ScrollDown.current++; //increasing the scroll variable so that it keeps scrolling
            $(window).scrollTop(ScrollDown.current);
            if(ScrollDown.current<ScrollDown.lastValue && ScrollDown.enabled){  
            //ScrollDown.current<ScrollDown.lastValue basically checks if it's reached the bottom
                if(prev!==ScrollDown.current-1){
                /*I'm checking if the user 
                scrolled up or down while the polling has been going on, 
                if the user scrolls up then prev<ScrollDown.current-1, 
                if the user scrolls down then prev>ScrollDown.current-1 
                and at the next poll() the scrolling will stop 
                because ScrollDown.enabled will bet set to false by ScrollDown.stop()*/
                    ScrollDown.stop();
                }
                poll();
            }
        },rate);
    })();
};

ScrollDown.stop=function(){
    ScrollDown.enabled=false;
};

ScrollDown.continue=function(){
    ScrollDown.enabled=true;
    switch (ScrollDown.lastType){
        case "fast":
            ScrollDown.fast(ScrollDown.lastValue);
            break;
        case "normal":
            ScrollDown.normal(ScrollDown.lastValue);
            break;
        case "slow":
            ScrollDown.slow(ScrollDown.lastValue);
            break;
    }
};

ScrollDown.fast=function(value){
    if(!ScrollDown.enabled){
        ScrollDown.continue();
    }else{
        ScrollDown.lastType='fast';
        ScrollDown.custom(value,1);
    }
};
ScrollDown.normal=function(value){
    if(!ScrollDown.enabled){
        ScrollDown.continue();
    }else{
        ScrollDown.lastType='normal';
        ScrollDown.custom(value,10);
    }
};
ScrollDown.slow=function(value){
    if(!ScrollDown.enabled){
        ScrollDown.continue();
    }else{
        ScrollDown.lastType='slow';
        ScrollDown.custom(value,50);
    }
};
function ScrollDown(){}
```

So if you were to call **ScrollDown.slow('bottom')** it would start scrolling slowly till it reaches the bottom of your page unless you scroll up or down manually, then it stops.

Answer (score -1):

You could set a variable to indicate that your call to animate was active, then check that variable inside the scroll handler.

```
window.IsAutoScrolling = true;
$("html,body").stop().animate({ "scrollTop": y }, 1000);
// Do something to set IsAutoScrolling = false, when the animation is done.

$(window).scroll(e){  
if(!window.IsAutoScrolling){  
    $("html,body").stop();  
}
```

Comment: This won't work because window.IsAutoScrolling will always be true until the scrolling stops...at which point we no longer care that the window is auto scrolling. The problem is detecting what is calling the scroll DURING the animate scroll; jquery or the user.