# How can I get jQuery to scroll down a div (to another div) on mouse over of a link?

Tags: jquery, html, scroll

Very hard to explain, I know.. especially since I'm new to the concept of programming altogether.

But I want to, on mouse over of a link to the right, change the logo so it corresponds with the link. I want it to animate so it 'scrolls' past all the other logos to get to the right one, kinda like what some websites have been doing as of late.

All the logos are contained within a div, and all have their own classes (if needed). Same goes with the links.

I'm certain one of you jQuery junkies can figure this out in a few lines of code.. or point me to a tutorial.  Help me pleaase!

**EDIT**: Okay, whilst jAndy's submission was very handy, I'm stuck on how to code it all up. Am I going about this the right way?

```
<div id="nav">
    <div id="nav_left">
        <h1 class="home"><em>name</em>:home</h1>
        <h1 class="about"><em>name</em>:about</h1>
        <h1 class="folio"><em>name</em>:folio</h1>
        <h1 class="contact"><em>name</em>:contact</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="nav_right">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="lhome">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="labout">About Me</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="lfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="lcontact">Contact Me</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Indeed difficult. Can you provide a link to a website which illustrates the desired behavior?

Comment: I will try and see what I can dig up..

Answer (score 4):

Easy going would look simiar to this example:

```
$('a.MyAnchorClass').bind('mouseenter', function(){
    $('div.MyDivClassWithLogos').animate({
       'scrollTop':    $('img.MyImgClass').offset().top
    }, 1500);
});
```

Example: http://jsbin.com/uliti3/2/edit

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#nav_left').find('h1').each(function(i,v){
       $.data(this, 'pos', $(this).offset());
    });

    $('#nav_right').find('a').bind('mouseenter', function(e){
       var _target = '.' + e.target.className.substr(1);

       $('#nav_left').stop(true, false).animate({
           'scrollTop':  $(_target).data('pos').top
       }, 1500);
    });
});
```

Comment: I've tried implementing this, but I really am stuck. Is it possible for you to look over the code and see if I'm div'ing everything the right way? (I've added the code above)

Comment: @jordsta: I've added an example

Comment: Excellent, this (nearly) does exactly what I want it to! It does seem to do this all randomly though, and always ends up at the bottom. I'll be uploading a demo shortly of what I mean..

Comment: @jordsta: i can't see the sourcecode right now since I'm on mobile phone watching worldcup. But it looks like you aren't using my latest example code (with caching offsets) do you?

Comment: Oh, no, I wasn't! Sorry, I thought it was a source for the first bit of code.. I'll try it out and see what happens.

Comment: I don't think it's doing anything different.. it's probably because it needs an offset though.

Comment: Okay, I'm still having massive troubles with this. It seems to scroll to the bottom of the div regardless of whatever link is hovered. Do you know what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

Check out Ariel Fleslers [scrollTo](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/) plugin

Answer (score 0):

Although jAndy's answer is probably what you want... I thought I would share another method seen in this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/m2zQE/2/)

I answered a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896869/jquery-changing-css-on-navigation-when-div-scrolls-into-view/2898109#2898109) using a menu system that worked by scrolling a div after clicking. I simply updated the demo by changing `click` to `mouseover`.

Comment: Actually, I find your method fits well. I'll have a go at it after I get my computer back up and running, in about a day or two.

Comment: I've actually ended up turning that code into a plugin, check it out here: https://github.com/Mottie/visualNav