# jQuery change class on navigation when div # scrolls horizontally into view

Tags: jquery, scrollview

I've seen this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896869/jquery-changing-css-on-navigation-when-div-scrolls-into-view) and it was pretty helpful but how about if the navigation is horizontally. I would like to change class into active on my active button by the moment the div scrolls into view from a horizontally navigation.

Right now the website I'm working on, scrolls both vertically and horizontally and by the time it reaches a div that has others divs on the same axis with it, it show the first div from the html selected, even though is not in current view.

So how can I check both axis and toggle class when div is actually in window view?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can catch the scroll event like this.

```
$('body').scroll(function(){

});
```

Following line gives you the scroll position.

```
$(window).scrollTop();
$(window).scrollLeft();
```

To notice the entering div compare the scroll-value and the div-offset every time the body is scrolled.

```
if( $('#div').offset().left < $(window).scrollLeft() )
{
    alert('I am in your view!');
}
```

Maybe you have to add the body width to the calculation.

To toggle a class there is a function named `toggleClass`. You can user `addClass` and `removeClass` too.

Comment: Thx, sorry about the late comment but i didn't get the notification of this answer, the body size is the screen size, is full 100% width? How do I add that?

Comment: If the with of the body equals the width of the screen you wouln't be able to scroll. But you don't need to know the body size. Just past the 3rd code block into the 1st. That should do it.

Comment: I will try that, thx. About de body size, I thought if the body would be the same size as the screen would still scroll because of the wider div inside it.