# Jquery if a div is visible on page?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a one page website.

As part of the navigation bar i would like it to highlight a certain link *if* a certain other div is visible on the page.

I have a feeling jquery will do this.

[Here is an example of what i mean.](http://peeltheorange.com/) 
Notice how the navigation links highlight if the section they link to is visible on the page

Can anyone help??

Comment: I have tried searching and searching for jquery code that changes if visible, but i keep getting code for if the css attribute "visible" is present, not if the div is literally visible on the page

Comment: I think you are actually looking for something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896869/jquery-changing-css-on-navigation-when-div-scrolls-into-view

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The other answers will return true **if an element is visible in the DOM** - even if they're styled as `display:none` and not actually 'visible' in a visual sense.

If you want to see if an element is currently visible in the viewport, one solution could be to look into using using [**Viewport Selectors for jQuery.**](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/viewport)

Then, you could check whether an element is currently in the viewport (I.E. physically visible) using the `$(":in-viewport")` selector.

[**Here's an example**](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/viewport/3x2.html) of it being used.

Comment: So the viewselector code can be used instead of .is(visible)?

Comment: @CaedanLavender Yep, if you're checking for the element actually being in the viewport. I'll add a link to an example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use :visible to check if something is visible.

Checking if an element is visible:

```
if($(element).is(':visible'))
```

http://api.jquery.com/is/

You can also select ones which are visible

```
var $list = $('li:visible');
```

You can also filter an existing array of jQuery elements

```
var $list = $('li');
var $visible = $list.filter(':visible');
```

http://api.jquery.com/filter/

Obviously you can apply this to any type of element.

Comment: Will this work if the element is literally visible or just if the css attribute "visible" is present, i have already tried something similar to the code you have given.

Comment: From my experienced it works with elements with CSS of display: none

Comment: It will also work if it is a child of an element that has display:none

Comment: i need it to highlight a link if a div is *literally visible* on the page, the css "display: none;" will not be used in the webpage.

Comment: In fact, from the documentation it states: "Elements with visibility: hidden or opacity: 0 are considered visible, since they still consume space in the layout." http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

Comment: Oh I see, so if the user will actually be able to see it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16429915/794897 @Zenith 's answer is best for this then :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
if($('selector').is(':visible')){
    $('selector2').show();
}
```

there is also a `.is('hidden')` that can be used.