# jQuery function issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, viewport

I have adapted someones example (from a previous Stack Overflow question I asked) to do what I want, but it doesn't seem to be working.

[If it helps then here is the link to that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16429831/jquery-if-a-div-is-visible-on-page)

The function that isn't working:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($('.orange').isOnScreen() === 'true'); {
        $('.box').css('background', 'red');
    }
});
```

[Here is the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/caedanlavender/LuYD2/2/)

When the orange square comes into the screen, the rest of the squares should change to red, and then when the orange square is not on the screen, the red squares need to turn blue again.

Comment: `true === 'true'` is will be false because `true` is boolean and `'true'` is string.

Comment: Changing 'true' to true makes the squares turn red even before the orange square is in the viewport.

Comment: you have a `;` before the `{}` block.

Comment: Also, the fiddle is missing $(window).scroll(...

Comment: After fixing numerous syntax errors, it works. http://jsfiddle.net/LuYD2/4/

Comment: That is much better, but it still doesnt change back to blue when the orange square disapears??

Comment: @KevinB nice work, I couldn't get it working even after fixing the 3 issues commented above lol.

Comment: @CaedanLavender Of course it doesn't, you don't have any logic in the code that will do that.

Comment: Oh the fiddle was missing a `$` before `('.orage')`, never mind it Joseph managed to fix it too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were a few problems in your syntax, but [this, though unoptimized, should work](http://jsfiddle.net/LuYD2/5/)

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    //isOnScreen returns a boolean, loose comparison will do
    if ($('.orange').isOnScreen()){
        $('.box').css('background', 'red');
    } else {
        //you need to revert back when isOnScreen returns false
        $('.box').css('background', 'blue');
    }
});
```

Comment: That is absolutely perfect, thankyou so much, i figured there would be syntax errors, there is so many brackets and semi-colons and i am really new to this stuff.

Comment: @CaedanLavender syntax errors can be caught using the console.

Comment: And also static code analysis tools such as http://www.jshint.com/ may help fixing those.

Comment: @Joseph the Dreamer You don't happen to be familiar with any free offline JavaScript/J-query consoles available for download do you?

Comment: you can also click "jshint" in that fiddle, it will mark the syntax errors.

Comment: jshint in the fiddle kept telling me my syntax was correct. Thats why i turned to stackoverflow

Comment: @CaedanLavender `true === 'true'` will not return true, and unlike static typing (C/Java) where you know the return is boolean, in JS you will never know what `isOnScreen` will return. These are things you look out for. Also, consoles are built-in in modern browsers. Hit F12.

Answer (score 0):

You had a few errors in logic and syntax.  Try this:

```
//This is the function that is playing up:
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($('.orange').isOnScreen()) {
        $('.box').css('background', 'red');
    }
    else {
        $('.box').css('background', 'blue');
    }
});
```

Updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LuYD2/8/