# Implementing One page web site's navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I am building one page web site which has a sticky navigation on it. I have implemented almost everything, but i couldn't implement the highlight to the navigation link when the user is scrolling by mouse wheel or browser's scroll bar instead of using the navigation. I guess this can be implemented by adding a pre-styled class to the section which is closest to the top?

My second question is how to stop the scrolling when user does something while the page is scrolling?

My site markup is

```
<nav class="columns col-12 main-nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#page1" class="selected">a link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page2">another link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page3">cat</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page4">dog</a></li>
        </ul>
</nav>


<div class="container">
    <section class="page" id="page1" data-stellar-background-ratio="1.75">

    </section>              
</div>
<div class="container">
    <section class="page" id="page2" data-stellar-background-ratio="1">

    </section>              
</div>
```

And this is my JQuery for navigation to scrolling to the corresponding id

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('a').click(function() {

    var el = $(this).attr('href');
    var elWrapped = $(el);

    scrollToEle(elWrapped, 40);

    return false;

});

function scrollToEle(element, navheight) {

    var offset = element.offset();
    var offsetTop = offset.top;
    var totalScroll = offsetTop - navheight;

    $('body,html').animate({
        scrollTop : totalScroll,
    }, 2000, 'easeInCirc');

}

 });
```

This is how i highlight the navigation link when user clicks it.(I think this is not a good way to do this)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('nav a').click(function() {
    $('nav .selected').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});



});
```

I am really sorry for my terrible English. I hope you understand my question. My question is how to highlight the link when the user scroll the page without using the navigation. And how to stop the scrolling when user click on the page while the page is scrolling.

Comment: Anyone know the answer?

Comment: [ScrollSpy](http://davidwalsh.name/mootools-scrollspy) will do the highlighting for you.

Comment: :) thanks i realy apriciate your answer. but i need to learn it how to do with jquery by coding. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer for my question from a different post. Here it is if someone find this usefull

[jQuery changing css on navigation when div # scrolls into view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896869/jquery-changing-css-on-navigation-when-div-scrolls-into-view)

```
$(window).height() // returns the viewport height
$(document).height() // returns the height of the entire document
$(window).scrollTop() // returns the Y position of the document that is at the top of the viewport



var topRange      = 200,  // measure from the top of the viewport to X pixels down
    edgeMargin    = 20,   // margin above the top or margin from the end of the page
    animationTime = 1200, // time in milliseconds
    contentTop = [];

$(document).ready(function(){

 // Stop animated scroll if the user does something
 $('html,body').bind('scroll mousedown DOMMouseScroll mousewheel keyup', function(e){
  if ( e.which > 0 || e.type == 'mousedown' || e.type == 'mousewheel' ){
   $('html,body').stop();
  }
 });

 // Set up content an array of locations
 $('#sidemenu').find('a').each(function(){
  contentTop.push( $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top );
 });

 // Animate menu scroll to content
  $('#sidemenu').find('a').click(function(){
   var sel = this,
       newTop = Math.min( contentTop[ $('#sidemenu a').index( $(this) ) ], $(document).height() - $(window).height() ); // get content top or top position if at the document bottom
   $('html,body').stop().animate({ 'scrollTop' : newTop }, animationTime, function(){
    window.location.hash = $(sel).attr('href');
   });
   return false;
 });

 // adjust side menu
 $(window).scroll(function(){
  var winTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
      bodyHt = $(document).height(),
      vpHt = $(window).height() + edgeMargin;  // viewport height + margin
  $.each( contentTop, function(i,loc){
   if ( ( loc > winTop - edgeMargin && ( loc < winTop + topRange || ( winTop + vpHt ) >= bodyHt ) ) ){
    $('#sidemenu li')
     .removeClass('selected')
     .eq(i).addClass('selected');
   }
  });
 });

});
```

And here

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/10144683/edit

```
// Assign the HTML, Body as a variable...
var $viewport = $('html, body');

// Some event to trigger the scroll animation (with a nice ease - requires easing plugin )...
$('#element').click(function() {
    $viewport.animate({ 
        scrollTop: scrollTarget // set scrollTarget to your desired position
    }, 1700, "easeOutQuint");
});

// Stop the animation if the user scrolls. Defaults on .stop() should be fine
$viewport.bind("scroll mousedown DOMMouseScroll mousewheel keyup", function(e){
    if ( e.which > 0 || e.type === "mousedown" || e.type === "mousewheel"){
         $viewport.stop().unbind('scroll mousedown DOMMouseScroll mousewheel keyup'); // This identifies the scroll as a user action, stops the animation, then unbinds the event straight after (optional)
    }
});
```