# How to highlight anchor link when target div comes in view in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a webpage like the following layout;

[image: Layout]

The HTML is;

```
<div class="header" style="text-align: center">Demo</div>
<div class="navi">
    <div class="title">
        Options
    </div>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <div class="da">
        <a href="#diva" class="current">diva</a>
        <a href="#divb">divb</a>
        <a href="#divc">divc</a>
        <a href="#divd">divd</a>
    </div>
    <div class="db">
        <div style="width: 300px; height: 300px; background-color: #996633"><a id="diva" name="diva">DIV1</a></div>
        <div style="width: 300px; height: 300px; background-color: #CC0066"><a id="divb" name="divb">DIV2</a></div>
        <div style="width: 300px; height: 300px; background-color: #3300FF"><a id="divc" name="divc">DIV3</a></div>
        <div style="width: 300px; height: 300px; background-color: #99CC00"><a id="divd" name="divd">DIV4</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">&nbsp;</div>
```

and CSS is;

```
html, body, div, h2, img, ul, li, form, time {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
html, body {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 800px;
}
.header{
  height: 40px;
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #666666;
}
.title{
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.content{
  margin-bottom: 36px;
}
.footer{
  height: 30px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-top: solid 1px #CCCCCC;
  background: #FFFFFF;
}

.da,.db{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  top: 82px;
  bottom: 30px;
}
.da{
  width: 200px;
  border-right: solid 1px #CCCCCC;
  overflow: visible !important;
}
.da a{
  font-family: Tahoma;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #555;
}
.da a:hover{
  background-color: #DDD;
}
.da .current,.da .current:hover{
  background-color: #FF6600;
}
.db{
  left: 200px;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #CC99FF;
  overflow: scroll;
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

The links of sidebar are anchored to 4 cascaded divs. They are linked to divs and when I click on links, the corresponding div will scroll up. This worked fine. But I tried to achieve something different. The link of current visible div may be given orange background color, so that when user scrolls the page, the orange color will shift from one link  to another, according to the current div on page. After some googling and research, I found this SO question useful **[jQuery changing css on navigation when div # scrolls into view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896869/jquery-changing-css-on-navigation-when-div-scrolls-into-view/2898109#2898109)**. A demo of the solution is available in this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m2zQE/)** which is exactly what I want.

But when I tried to implement this solution in my layout, it is not working, ie, links are not highlighting to corresponding div.

**[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/GLLsv/)** is my fiddle.

How can I implement the same in my layout?

Comment: Have you tried my solution? Is that helpful bro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

**CSS:**

```
.da,.db{
  position: relative; // changed to relative. Because of absolute your document height is affected.
  z-index: 0;
  top: 82px;
  bottom: 30px;
}

.db{
  left: 142px;
    top:42px;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #CC99FF;
  overflow: scroll;
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.da a').removeClass('current').eq(i).addClass('current'); // replaced selected with current which you are using.
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/GLLsv/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't wrap my head around some of these answers, but I found this really simple idea.

It's basically saying that the mouse will be in view at some position on the screen, and if it is within a specific div, highlight the matching link.

**HTML**

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav">
    <span id ="menu">&#9776;</span> 
    <ul id="top-menu">
        <li><a href="#one" class="links">Menu 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#two" class="links">Menu 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#three" class="links">Menu 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#four" class="links">Menu 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#five" class="links">Menu 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#six" class="links">Menu 6</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="one" class="container">
        one
    </div>
    <div id="two" class="container">
        two
    </div>
    <div id="three" class="container">
        three
    </div>
    <div id="four" class="container">
        four
    </div>
    <div id="five" class="container">
        five
    </div>
    <div id="six" class="container">
        six
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
*{
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;

}

body{
    font-family: Geneva, Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
    margin: 0px;
}

.nav{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background: rgba(200,200,200,0.2);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
}

#menu{
    float: right;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding-right: 20px;
    color: rgba(100,100,100,0.9);;
}

.nav ul{
    width: 150px;
    list-style-type: none;
    background: rgba(200,200,200,0.2);
    border-radius: 5px;
}

#top-menu{
   clear: both;
   display: block;
   float: right;
   padding-left: 0px;
   margin-top: 10px;
   margin-right: 20px;

}
.links{
    color: black;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.nav ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    padding: 2px 0px 2px 10px;
}
.nav ul li a:hover{
    color: #fff;
    background-color: black;
    border-left: thick solid red;
}

#wrapper{
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.container{
    width: 800px;
    height: 600px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    background: rgba(200,200,200,0.2);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(200,200,200,1);
    padding: 20px;
}

.active{
    color: white;
    background-color: rgba(100,100,100,1);
    border-left: thick solid rgba(0,255,0,0.5);
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $("div").mouseenter(function(){
     var id = $(this).attr('id');
     $('a').removeClass('active');
     $("[href=#"+id+"]").addClass('active');
   });

});
```

[Source](http://codepen.io/xblack/pen/JGtfd)