# Detect jquery event trigger by user or call by code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some `window.onscroll` event

```
$(window).scroll(function(e){
    //My Stuff
});
```

but in my code I call animate scroll to some where

```
$('html, body').stop().animate({
   scrollTop:555
}, 1000);
```

so how I detect the page was scroll by user or call by my code. My current solution is put a flag before call `animate` in my code then clear it but it's not clever solution. I've also read about detect `e.which` or `e.originalEvent` but it's not work. I think you expert have a good solution here.

Comment: Wait, why the flag solution isn't good enough? What's not clever with it?

Comment: @gdoron: Flag once set to true will always be true because he can't detect whether user scrolled himself and there by set that flag to false again as far as I understand from the question.

Comment: I have call the animate in multiple place, so update all of them will not smart enough. But then what happen when user interrupt the animate by scroll the page? The flag cannot help

Comment: @Sarfraz flag can be set to false when the animate complete (in jquery)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
$('#scroller').scroll(function(e) {
    if (e.originalEvent) {
        // scroll happen manual scroll
        console.log('scroll happen manual scroll');
    } else {
        // scroll happen by call
        console.log('scroll happen by call');
    }
});

$('#scroller').scroll(); // just a initial call
```

When you scroll by call the `e.originalEvent` will `undefined` but when scroll manually it will give `scroll` object.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QStkd/290/)**

Comment: Hey, interesting. If I use `$('#scroller').scroll();` then it can detect happen by call, but if I use `$('#scroller').animate({scrollTop: 200}, 1000);` it said manual scroll. Is that a lie?

Comment: Does not work for me: e.originalEvent is always there and identical in both cases.

Comment: Using jQuery 1.12.3, e.originalEvent is always there. I mean for manual trigger or not (not tested for animation). Though, to be precise, the scroll event is called because after an animation (on callback) I set back the original scroll value.

Comment: Can this be altered, so that it works without jQuery too?

Answer (score 3):

ive reasked this question and got 2 helpful answers.
i'll link the question here for others who'll find this thread.

[Detect if a scroll event is triggered manually in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20737937/2592207)