# javascript origin of function

Tags: jquery, function

I've got a Jquery function:

```
$('#element').click(function(){..........});
```

Is there a way to check in this function whether it was triggered by real mouse or just by script `$('#element').click();`?

Thanks for answers.

Comment: similar here as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11049287/detect-jquery-event-trigger-by-user-or-call-by-code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can check ***e.originalEvent***:

```
$('#element').click(function(e){
  if (e.originalEvent !== undefined)
  {
    alert ('Mouse clicked');
  }
  else 
  {
    alert( 'triggered programmatically' );   
  }
});
```

Comment: That works quite well: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s7aH3/)