# How to distinguish between an element that is scrolled into view vs. autoscrolled into view

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently using the following JavaScript function to detect whether an element is scrolled into view:

```
function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();
    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    return ((elemTop <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}
```

Now, I need to distinguish whether this element was autoscrolled on page load (e.g. via #anchor-tag) or manually scrolled into view.

What is a good way of doing this?

Comment: This is what ended up working for me:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/7210072/145536

Answer (score 0):

When an anchor is clicked, the URL hash changes. You can use [`window.onhashchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onhashchange) to detect that:

```
window.onhashchange = function() {
    console.log(window.location.hash);
}
```

Comment: True but this solution will not work in my case because all the URLs will have the # as part of the URL.