# Is it possible to differentiate between programmatic and user scrolling in dojo?

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

I have a floating bar at the top which is being shown/hidden as user scrolls the page up or down. I need to hide it completely when Dojo/browser scrolls the page programmatically, e.g. when putting focus on an invalid element in a form.

Is it possible to know that the scrolling occurred because of user input?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect whether scroll event was created by user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7035896/detect-whether-scroll-event-was-created-by-user)

Comment: Not a perfect duplicate, but since the answer to that question is "that can't be done in JavaScript at all", the answer is the same if you include Dojo.  (Detecting when Dojo itself does the scrolling might be possible, but won't cover all cases.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can't be done in general, but can be done in the specific case mentioned in the question, namely to detect that the scrolling occurred because Dojo is trying to put focus on an invalid element in a form. To do that it's necessary to override the `validate` method in `dijit/form/Form` so that it can automatically override the `focus` method in all widgets in the form:

```
    validate: function(){
        var self = this;
        var children = this._getDescendantFormWidgets();
        array.forEach(children, function(child){
            if(typeof(child.focus) === "function" && !child._uuiIsModded){
                child._uuiOldFocus = child.focus;
                child.focus = self._onProgrammaticFocus;
                child._uuiIsModded = true;
            }
        });

        return this.inherited(arguments);
    },

    _onProgrammaticFocus: function(){
        topic.publish("on-programmatic-focus", this);
        this._uuiOldFocus.apply(this, arguments);
    },
```

The new `validate` method amends all widgets contained in a form. The amendment is to replace the standard `focus` method with a custom method `_onProgrammaticFocus`, which fires the event `on-programmatic-focus` before calling the standard `focus` method. That way the event is fired only when the focus is put on the widget programmatically in response to a validation error and not when the widget is selected by the user:

- when user puts focus on a widget by selecting the widget with a mouse or tapping on it the `focus` method IS NOT CALLED
- when the form widget contains invalid value, the standard behavior of the `validate` method is to amend the widget with CSS classes that show the validation error and put focus on the widget by calling the `focus` method. In this case the focus should be already amended and fire the "on-programmatic-focus" event.

Please remember, that this is a hack that replaces the standard `focus` method and may not work if there are problems in other parts of your code. Specifically, in some cases `__uuiOldFocus` may become undefined if your widgets containing other widgets don't inherit `dijit/_Container`. This is because `this._getDescendantFormWidgets()` returns different children than method `toObject` from `dom/dom-form`. The method `this._getDescendantFormWidgets()` used in form validation relies on the fact that all widgets containing other widgets should inherit the `dijit/_Container` mixin (which initializes `this.containerNode` with the current DOM node).