# Use jQuery to detect if user has scrolled page manually (via keyb, mousewheel etc)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I developed a webpage which loads and positions itself at a certain vertical scroll position for the user (depending on various factors unique to their account). It is not suitable to use a url anchor/hash in this case

Instead I use jQuery to scroll to the desired position, in the $(document).ready

This all works fine, except the page also tends to contain hotlinked images

Once these images have loaded, it suddenly results in the page becoming longer (and the position I automatically scrolled to is no longer accurate).. 
In Chrome at least, it doesn't compensate and just leaves the user staring at the same vertical pixel scroll position.

So I now plan to improve this by doing a 2nd scrollTo in $(window).load(), after all images have been loaded.... but only if the user has not already scrolled from the original position I set in document.ready()

What would be the best way to detect this?

Comment: where is your code????

Comment: Would it not be better if you specify height of the hotlinked images so that the entire problem doesn't originate?

Comment: @Awol, I cannot really do that. The dimensions of hotlinked images are not known until they have already loaded. I could limit them to a max height but they may be much smaller, so I would still have the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`.scroll` method](https://api.jquery.com/scroll/) to detect when a user scrolls a page.

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/7bg13u75/1/)**

[Reference this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7035896/detect-whether-scroll-event-was-created-by-user) for a more detailed function/code.

Comment: Thanks! This is perfect as it covers all scroll methods (keyboard, mouse wheel etc)