# How to detect user manualy move the scroll or by script in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In Javascript, I want to detect whether the user move the scroll bar or the scroll bar moved by script. I have write the code to move the div scrollbar using javascript. Here i want to differentiate the scroll position whether the user manually moved or it moved by script. I have used below code. But it detects all.

```
$("#log").scroll(function(e) {
    console.log("scrolling");
});

var logDiv = document.getElementById('log');

logDiv.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', function() {
    console.log("mouseEvent");
    userManualScroll = true; 
});
```

Pls help me.

Comment: so basically in the document, you need to know scroll event has triggered or not

Comment: Actually, scroll event triggered by manualy or by script (example:  $("#log").scrollTop(10))

Comment: This link is very well written you can refer here, let me know if it worked for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7035896/detect-whether-scroll-event-was-created-by-user

Comment: this document is useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set a global variable

`var userscroll = true;`

Whenever you adjust scroll position via JS, set userscroll to false before the scroll operation and true afterwards.

In any functions that only trigger on the user scrolling, add an if-clause

```
if (userscroll) {
   ...
```