# how to differentiate scroll done by JS and scroll done by user?

Tags: javascript

I have a small website that starts to scroll to show user the entire content after some short time of inactivity.

I have one *event listener* that listens if user is active and if not it starts scrolling automatically. The problem is that this automatic scroll makes the website think that it's scroll by the user, which is not.

Is there a way how to tell difference if the scroll is done by user or by JavaScript?

```
// this line in an infinite loop using is causing the page to scroll
window.scrollTo(0, 200)
// this is detecting the scrolling
window.onscroll = (event) => {
   // maybe get the information somehow from the event??
   if (event.scrolledBy == 'user'){
       activity = true
   }
}
```

can't I duplicate the function and set some sort of id of it? Let's say

```
window.scrollToAutomat = window.scrollTo
```

and then do some magic?

Comment: Can't you set a sort of state somewhere every time the automatic scrolling gets fired? This same state can be updated whenever this automatic scrolling is done. It should be easier to identify this scrolling than the one fired by the user.

Comment: think about what might the user do to make the scroll, identify the user with mouse events, put a boolean in the mousemovement eventHandler and if true reset it after the scroll

Comment: Unfortunately `isTrusted` is `true` when you use `scrollTo`. Eugen's idea might be the best

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect whether scroll event was created by user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7035896/detect-whether-scroll-event-was-created-by-user)

Comment: @melancia it sort of fires sequence of commands to scroll to given position so that's probably not possible. You could also wait until it's done, but it can also get interrupted by the user. And never achieve the destination it was going to

Comment: From the suggested question (@PredaBogdan), that's the answer that works around what I mentioned: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47553150/2191976

Comment: @EugenSunic, listening for mouse events would not be sufficient as the user might be scrolling the page in many different ways (e.g. pgUp/pgDown keys, up/down keys, tab key jumping from an element to the following one, mouse wheel, click & drag on the scrolling bar, etc...). Listening for all potential events would be a nightmare. Even more so if you have to take into consideration touch events too.

Comment: @melancia thanks, that looks promising. I will check it. It was matter of naming the problem right and search the solution

Comment: @secan that s true you d have to cover those "edge" cases, it was just a suggestion on to initialy approach the problem

Comment: I am a bit more Python person, so I would assume that cloning the function and changing its insides would work. "Ok scrollTo clone, now you are clone behave like this and that", is something like that not a possible solution?

css `scroll-behavior: smooth;` makes it impossible to use @melancia solution, because then it doesn't trigger one scroll but multiple scroll events