# With javascript / query, is there a way to just "nudge" or "flick" the scroll so it's interruptible by the user (better description within)

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, user-experience

I want some js to automatically scroll just a slight bit down the page, however I also want this scroll to be interruptible by the user.

When using jquery to auto scroll, when you animate the scroll with .animate and then the user starts scrolling while the animation scroll is still going they interact with each other and create a strange jumping effect.

Is there a way to make so when the user scroll during a javascript scroll it just stop the javascript scroll?

Comment: I completely changed my answer, you better check it out... Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

**It can't be done since you can't know if the end-user scrolled or you scrolled the page via javascript.**

> A scroll event is sent whenever the element's scroll position changes, regardless of the cause. A mouse click or drag on the scroll bar, dragging inside the element, pressing the arrow keys, or using the mouse's scroll wheel could cause this event.

[Docs](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/)

---

**What I tried to do but failed because the above:**

```
// callback for the scroll event
$(document.body).scroll(function(){
    // Stop the scrolling!
    $('html, body').stop();
});
```

[A not working demo...](http://jsfiddle.net/Lwvba/3/)

Answer (score 0):

The other users answer is actually incorrect, it is possible and has been answered before:
[How can I differentiate a manual scroll (via mousewheel/scrollbar) from a Javascript/jQuery scroll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834667/how-can-i-differentiate-a-manual-scroll-via-mousewheel-scrollbar-from-a-javasc)

Check the answer

```
"$('body,html').bind('scroll mousedown wheel DOMMouseScroll mousewheel keyup', function(e){
 if ( e.which > 0 || e.type == "mousedown" || e.type == "mousewheel"){
  $("html,body").stop();
 }
})"
```

I've updated the previous users JS Fiddle to work with the proposed solution and it works perfectly.
http://jsfiddle.net/Lwvba/7/