# Have page auto-scroll - but stop auto scrolling when the user manually scrolls (jquery?)

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Not sure of the best way to do this.

I have some code to automatically scroll, like this:

```
$("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: $('html, body').get(0).scrollHeight
}, (60000));
```

And I thought I could "stop" this scrolling by adding this:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    $("html, body").stop();
});
```

But it looks like that second bit of code is firing when the first bit of code executes. So I'm not achieving anything.

I just need a way to have the auto-scroll stop when the user wants to manually scroll or move the scroll bar.

All ideas welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('body,html').bind('scroll mousedown wheel DOMMouseScroll mousewheel keyup', function(e){
 if ( e.which > 0 || e.type == "mousedown" || e.type == "mousewheel"){
  $("html,body").stop();
 }
});
```

I found your answer at

[How can I differentiate a manual scroll (via mousewheel/scrollbar) from a Javascript/jQuery scroll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834667/how-can-i-differentiate-a-manual-scroll-via-mousewheel-scrollbar-from-a-javasc)

I've added jsbin to describe

http://jsbin.com/dujuxihota/1/edit?js,output

Comment: I have another question. I am using this code: `$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('html, body').get(0).scrollHeight }, 6000);` but after 6 seconds it still hasn't reached the bottom. I have a setInterval to change the page after 6 seconds, so it's very important that the scroll reaches the bottom before the 6 seconds is up. Is there something wrong with the code I'm using?