# Stop page scroll jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

In JavaScript I am looking for a moment when user scrolls to some `<div>`. Then I want to stop user's inertial scrolling and scroll to some another object via script.

How can I stop the scrolling which has already started?

So I want something like this:

```
$('#selector').stopScrolling().scrollTo('#another_object');
```

I know that `$('#selector').stop()` stops animations, but it seems like it can't help me there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `.scrollTo()`, use

```
// see http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/09/animated-scrolling-with-jquery-12/
$('html,body').animate({ scrollTo: 0 }, 1000);
```

then you can stop the scrolling using

```
// see http://stackoverflow.com/a/2836104/145346
$('html,body').stop();
```