# Scroll Diffrence

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

My Question is straight. Is there any way to detect that the scroll to a page has been due to javascript or mouse scroll. I really need to identify the difference.

Is there anybody who can help me to figure out the difference between the scroll made by mouse of a user or it has been due to jQuery or java script scroll event

I am working on a co browsing app, so there is transfer of events among multiple users. I am able to manage all the events except scroll. It lets the system to infinite scroll if scrolling from agent.html is recorded. you can see the app by opening the urls **182.71.103.93/screen2/client23122014.html** and then **182.71.103.93/job_tree**

Comment: Listen mousescrolls ...

Comment: I am working won a co browsing app, so there is transfer of events among multiple users. I am able to manage all the events except scroll. It lets the system to infinite scroll. you can see the app by opening 182.71.103.93/screen2/client23122014.html and then 182.71.103.93/job_tree

Comment: I would like to draw your attention to this question as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27653703/socket-io-node-js-mouse-tracking-as-soon-as-it-stops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer give by Termhn was good enough but if anyone stuck to the similar situation as of mine then you may use a global javascript variable

i did it in a way

For Client / user side

```
var emit_scroll_event=true;

socket.on('agentwindowscroll',function (msg){emit_scroll_event=false;  jQuery(document).scrollTop(msg);   });

//window scroll logic goes here
jQuery(document).scroll(function()
{
    var scrollFromTop=jQuery(document).scrollTop();
    if(emit_scroll_event)
    {
    socket.emit('windowscroll', scrollFromTop);
    }
    emit_scroll_event=true;
});
```

For Agent side we may use similar code

```
var emit_scroll_event=true;
//agent window scroll logic goes here
jQuery(document).scroll(function()
{
    var scrollFromTop=jQuery(document).scrollTop(); 
    if(emit_scroll_event)
    {
    socket.emit('agentwindowscroll', scrollFromTop);
    }
    emit_scroll_event=true;
});
 //responding to client scroll
  socket.on('windowscroll',function (msg){emit_scroll_event=false;   jQuery(document).scrollTop(msg);   });
```

***Note: This is not entire code. It is just the part of code that i used which helped me to sort out mine issue. It is not for normal javascript. It is used with Node js with Scoket.io module***

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you're asking but this will detect a mouse wheel event and therefore if it's not a mousewheel event it's caused by JS. You can use the "mousewheel" ("DOMMouseScroll" in Firefox) event in JS. Example:

```
// Chrome/Safari/Opera/New IE
$('html','body').addEventListener("mousewheel", MouseWheelHandler, false);

// Firefox
$('html','body').addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", MouseWheelHandler, false);

// Old IE
$('html','body').addEventListener("onmousewheel", MouseWheelHandler, false);

var MouseWheelHandler = function(e) {
  var e = window.event || e; //IE support
  var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (e.wheelDelta || -e.detail)));

  // Do whatever with the delta value
}
```

Comment: Your answer is close enough, but what to do if user scrolls the page by dragging page or browser scroller

Comment: I am working won a co browsing app, so there is transfer of events among multiple users. I am able to manage all the events except scroll. It lets the system to infinite scroll. you can see the app by opening http://182.71.103.93/screen2/client23122014.html and then http://182.71.103.93/job_tree

Comment: Hmm interesting problem. You could try this solution; it's similar to mine but more complete http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834667/how-can-i-differentiate-a-manual-scroll-via-mousewheel-scrollbar-from-a-javasc

Comment: I would like to draw your attention to this question as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27653703/socket-io-node-js-mouse-tracking-as-soon-as-it-stops