# jQuery carousel scroll jitter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a problem with jquery carousel data-slide, I've set it to scroll to the content and it works but when you try to scroll up, the page jitters.

I was able to stop it using

```
e.preventDefault();
```

But that created other problems in the carousel headers, they stopped moving and changing classes when they become active.

This is my JS

```
$(".scrolltotab").click(function(e) {

    var hre = e.currentTarget.href;
    var id = hre.split("#");
    id = id[1];

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#custom_carousel").offset().top
    }, 1000);

})

$('#custom_carousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function(evt) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#custom_carousel").offset().top
    }, 1000);

    $('#custom_carousel .controls li.active').removeClass('active');
    $('#custom_carousel .controls li:eq(' + $(evt.relatedTarget).index() + ')').addClass('active');

})

$(".customnum").keydown(function(e) {
    // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, enter and .
    if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110, 190]) !== -1 ||
        // Allow: Ctrl+A, Command+A
        (e.keyCode == 65 && (e.ctrlKey === true || e.metaKey === true)) ||
        // Allow: home, end, left, right, down, up
        (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 40)) {
        // let it happen, don't do anything
        return;
    }
    // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
    if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because when user try to scroll during the scroll animation, then the scroll position will keep switch between user's and animation's until the animation stop. So, by 
[This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834667/how-can-i-differentiate-a-manual-scroll-via-mousewheel-scrollbar-from-a-javasc)
You can try to register `mousewheel` event, which happens when people scroll, but not happens when js scroll, so you can try to register another event:

```
// Stop anime when user scrolls
var onMosueWheel = function(e) {
  $('html, body').stop(); 
};

// Register the mousewheel event.
$(document).on('mousewheel', onMosueWheel);
```

Tested on your site by chrome dev-tool.

Comment: I didn't add `keydown` events to stop the animation when user press `arrowUp` or `arrowDown`, if you also want to prevent that, add `keydown`  event and check the keycode in that function.